# Add a UITableViewControler to a UIView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, appcelerator, subview

I am writing an appcelerator module, which means I am handed a subclassed UIView to work with and create my visual controls in Objective C.

I am trying to add a tableview with a searchbar, but most samples online use rootViewController and UITableViewControler.

so...in order to add a tableview to the current view, do I need to create a tableview and a UITableViewController and add them somehow as subviews to the current view ?

I tried adding a MainViewController.h & MainViewController.m which is defined as

```
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
```

and then in my view

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    [self addSubview:mainView.view];
}

-(void)frameSizeChanged:(CGRect)frame bounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    if(CGRectIsEmpty(self.frame))
    {
        self.frame = bounds;
        [self addSubview:mainView.view];
    }
}
```

but it did not work, I just got an empty view. any ideas ? a sample code would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Where do you set the `frame` for `mainView`?

Comment: well.. I don't. I just used the mainviewcontroller files from apple sample tableSearch (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html), I figured if I get this table running in my view, there rest is easier. I looked and they did not set the frame in this sample

Comment: It seems, in the sample mainView is created from nib. `[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];`

Comment: yes, I just found it myself.. bummer. can you explain or point me to an example of a UITableViewController based subclass being loaded into an existing view and creates it own tableview... this is what I need to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


UITableView *TableListView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5,-1,331,425) style:1];
TableListView.editing=NO;
TableListView.delegate=self;
TableListView.dataSource=self;
TableListView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.000000 green:0.591928 blue:1.000000 alpha:1.000000];
TableListView.separatorStyle=1;
TableListView.rowHeight=40;
TableListView.tag=0;
TableListView.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
TableListView.clipsToBounds=YES;
[self.view addSubview:TableListView];
[TableListView release];

}
```

Hope this helps get you started...

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out and let you know. BTW, there is no tableviewcontroller in your sample code, why is it missing ? don't I need it ?